# Derby DB not finding tables

Tags: java, derby

I've connected to an embedded database but I am having trouble with the program finding the tables created. Is anyone able to pick out the issue? I have included the screenshot below.

[image: issue]

or if that's too small, a link here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBBNV.png

*EDIT*
It works fine using the client Driver and new Connection but not embedded. Any Ideas why?

I'm going to make a program that holds records on a single computer so I'm trying to keep it all together.

Comment: You are doing `create=true`. Could that be it? Time is evanescent.

Comment: I dropped the create=true and it didn't change anything =(

Answer (score 4):

You are very likely to see different databases. You are using the *embedded driver* which does not support connections from different JVMs. So you can’t see the same database in your IDE *and* your stand-alone application.

But both applications can have a different current directory against which your database name “sample” is resolved. Since you already ran your application with the `create=true` option that second database now exists. So it doesn’t help removing this option now.

In order to connect to the right database you have to either provide the full path to the database or change the current directory before connecting. But you will have to close the IDE’s connection if you use the embedded drivers though.